# Vector Tension Using Calculus

Tags: calculus

> A clothesline is tied between two poles, 8m apart. The line is quite
>   taut and has negligible sag. When a wet shirt with a mass of 0.8kg is
>   hung at the middle of the line, the midpoint is pulled down 8cm. Find
>   the tension in each half of the clothesline.

I am trying to solve this problem similar to how this problem is solved:

[image]

The problem I am having is that I am getting the same angle for both tension formulas. I can show my work if needed.

Answer:

[image]

My work:

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason you think the angles should be different?

Comment: i added the answer, also when I calculated with the same angle number, it led to mulitplying by 0

Comment: Those vectors look right (aside from the fact that it should be $1.96$ rather than $196$).

Comment: im pretty sure it is 196, but I am just adding the answer to help anyone who would like to explain . I am still stuck unfortunately

Comment: Ah you're right I used the wrong units at one point. I think it might be helpful if you can try to explain more exactly where you are stuck, because I see you have accepted a fairly detailed answer explaining this problem  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2327996/tension-of-each-half-using-vectors). Are you not satisfied with this answer?

Comment: i appreciated the detailed answer, but i struggled to understand it completely, also i was hoping it could be done in a more similar way like the picture i have because i know how to solve that problem

Comment: i added my failed attempt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one small mistake you have made, but you are on the right track. The $\theta$ value on the left of your picture (which I will call $\theta_l$) is not $-1.1457^\circ$. It's just $1.1457^\circ$. You can see this geometrically from the picture. Note that if you type

$$\tan^{-1}{\frac{-8}{400}}$$

into your calculator it will give you a value in the range $(-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2})$, which is why it gave you $-1.1457^\circ$ However, the tip of $\vec{T_1}$ is in the third quadrant so that vector is actually at an angle of $-1.1457^\circ + 180^\circ = 178.8543^\circ$ measured from the positive $x$ axis. So $\theta_l = 180^\circ - 178.8543^\circ = 1.1457^\circ$. Most of that is not necessary to go through though. You can just see from the symmetry of the situation that the angle on the left must equal the angle on the right.

Aside from this, your answer is so far correct. All you are trying to do is solve the system of equations at the bottom of the page. You have found from the equation

$$
-| \vec{T_1}|\cos{1.1457^\circ} + |\vec{T_2}|\cos{1.1457^\circ} = 0
$$

that $|T_1| = |T_2|$. You can now substitute $|\vec{T_1}|$ for $|\vec{T_2}|$ in the second equation, which would look like

$$
|\vec{T_1}|\sin{1.1457^\circ} + |\vec{T_1}|\sin{1.1457^\circ} = 0.8g
$$

You should be able to solve this and proceed. Note that I've made another small change to the right hand side of this last equation. You forgot to include multiplication by $g$, the acceleration due to gravity.

EDIT: The reason why they didn't bother multiplying by $g$ in the book is because for that problem the units were in pounds. A pound is a unit of force, whereas a kilogram is a unit of mass. You need to multiply the mass by $g$ to find the corresponding force in Newtons.

Comment: ah let me try again

Comment: wow, tyvm.. i would have had no idea to use physics knowledge as i have yet to take the courses. but i got the answer.

Comment: sorry, i realized that and deleted the question. Note to self g = 9.8 m/s^2